# How can we resize the LVM in Fedora 17?

Tags: lvm

I was trying to install Backtrack along with Fedora 17. While installing the BT I found there was no free space in my system. When I checked the FS in Fedora, all my space in HDD is used as LVM.

Answer (score 2):

When installing Fedora 17 it defaults to using the logical volume manager.  There is an LVM tool/gui that makes LVM management easy.  Install this tool by:

```
yum install system-config-lvm
```

A couple of considerations:

1. If you want to increase the size of an LV then you may use the gui to do this providing you have unused space on your drive.
2. If you want to reduce the size of an LV you can use the gui for a non-root LV.  A non root LV would be like:

   ```
   /dev/mapper/vg_your_node_name-lv_books   20G  1.1G   18G   6% /books
   ```
3. If you want to reduce the size of an LV and it is a root LV you cannot/must not use the gui.

   For example purpose we will use as our volume group:

   ```
   /dev/mapper/vg_your_node_name-lv_home   100G  1.1G   18G   6% /home
   ```

   Write this down to use later in the procedure.  Not this example but yours!

   This is a root volume group type and must not be managed by the gui.

   #### STEPS TO REDUCE A VOLUME GROUP:

   1. Insert your original FC 17 DVD and boot.  It will ask if you want to do a fresh install or repair a file system.  Choose the “repair” option.  There will be some questions so answer accordingly up to the one that asks about mounting your file systems.  At this point there is a “skip” option.  Select it and you will be taken to a shell login ( blank screen).  You do not want to mount your filesystems because they must be unmounted for resizing

      ```
      ## login as root
      $ df -h
      ```
   2. make sure no LVMs are mounted (they should not be)  If they are then:

      ```
      $ umount /dev/mapper/vg_your_node_name-lv_books (our example)
      $ vgchange -a y
      ```
   3. check the filesystem for errors

      ```
      $ e2fsck -f /dev/mapper/vg_your_node_name-lv_books
      ```
   4. shrink the filesystem to 30 G

      ```
      $ resize2fs -p /dev/mapper/vg_your_node_name-lv_books 30G
      ```
   5. reduce the size of the underlying logical volume

      ```
      $ lvreduce -L 30G /dev/mapper/vg_your_node_name-lv_books
      ```
   6. check if logical volume and filesystem are ok

      ```
      $ e2fsck -f /dev/mapper/vg_your_node_name-lv_books
      $ resize2fs -p /dev/mapper/vg_your_node_name-lv_books
      ```
   7. should get a “nothing to do” response at this point

      ```
      $ reboot
      ```

Some useful LVM commands (package lvm2-2.02.06-4):

- lvmdiskscan
- vgdisplay
- pvdisplay
- lvdispay
- vgcreate
- pvcreate
- lvscan
- pvscan
- vgscan

You can refer detailed steps [here](http://allaboutfedora.blogspot.in/2007/01/how-to-resize-or-expand-lvm-partitions.html) for extending of same.